# Ubuntu not booting after BIOS update boot-repair disk fail

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

Hey complete Linux noob here.

I've been struggling with getting my Ubuntu boot up and running after a bios update.

After the update when booting windows i got the error message INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DRIVE which somehow resolved it self through the windows recovery tools.

When booting Ubuntu I get dropping to shell message, along with error message telling me that the UUID of my boot doesn't exist.

I just tried to use the boot-repair disk however it doesn't show the recommended repair option for me hence I took a log http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NCVjn5g9jp.

I read on a forum (cant find the link right now, I've read so many posts this week) that this might be related to the storage controller settings in BIOS. A user found a solution changing this setting to AHCI. Mine is set to RST right now although when trying to change it i'm prompted with a warning that it will delete all my data.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Boot-repair is not finding your hard disk at all. Do you have multiple HDD's? Are they internal or external drives? Laptop or desktop? Is Windows booting now? Does the BIOS find your HDD? What setting does the BIOS show for your disks... AHCI, RAID, RST, IDE, other?

Comment: Yes I find that to be really weird. I have two SSD one where I have Windows installed along with a a ubuntu that I no longer use. The second SSD I use for the ubuntu OS that I'm currently using (none of the ubuntu installations will boot). The BIOS finds my SSD. The only thing I can see is that they are non RAID disks and that the I guess this is is general but that the storage controller is set to RST which can be changed to AHCI, those are the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to reinstall Windows...

**Some folks have found the 2nd choice that I provide easier to do...**

## Make sure to have a backup of your important Windows files!

You've got a single SSD set up in RAID mode, and the Ubuntu installer won't recognize your SSD until you switch your disk setting in the BIOS from RAID to AHCI.

Making that switch comes with some problems though, as Windows will no longer boot.

**Choice #1:** Looking at this article https://samnicholls.net/2016/01/14/how-to-switch-sata-raid-to-ahci-windows-10-xps-13/ will show you how to make the change without having to reinstall Windows.

- Boot to Windows with your current SATA controller configuration
- Open Device Manager
- Expand Storage Controllers and identify the Intel SATA RAID Controller
- View properties of the identified controller
- On the Driver tab, click the Update driver… button
- Browse my computer…, Let me pick…
- Uncheck Show compatible hardware
- Select Microsoft as manufacturer
- Select Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller as model
- Accept that Windows cannot confirm that this driver is compatible
- Save changes, reboot to BIOS and change RAID SATA Controller to AHCI
- Save changes and reboot normally, hopefully to Windows

Now you should be able to install Ubuntu in a dual-boot configuration.

**Choice #2:** See http://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/

- Right-click the Windows Start Menu. Choose Command Prompt (Admin).
- If you don’t see Command Prompt listed, it’s because you have already been updated to a later version of Windows.  If so, use this method instead to get to the Command Prompt:
- Click the Start Button and type cmd
- Right-click the result and select Run as administrator
- Type this command and press ENTER: bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal
- If this command does not work for you, try bcdedit /set safeboot minimal
- Restart the computer and enter BIOS Setup (the key to press varies between systems).
- Change the SATA Operation mode to AHCI from either IDE or RAID (again, the language varies).
- Save changes and exit Setup and Windows will automatically boot to Safe Mode.
- Right-click the Windows Start Menu once more. Choose Command Prompt (Admin).
- Type this command and press ENTER: bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot
- If you had to try the alternate command above, you will likely need to do so here also: bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot
- Reboot once more and Windows will automatically start with AHCI drivers enabled.

Comment: I will try to get this done ASAP thank you! In option 1 in the end you say that I should be able to install Ubuntu again after the steps, you don't think that the OS I already have can be salvaged?

Comment: Thank you sooo much for the help! Everything works now!

Comment: @SinaMohammadi glad it's all working for you now!